# What is this 90s shareware turn-based strategy vehicle tactics game?

Tags: story-identification, video-games

I'm trying to dig up a game I played as a child. Things I remember:

- The game used conventional Windows UI and buttons, a bit like *Castle of the Winds*.
- I would have played the game on Windows 98 or 95.
- The game had a top-down perspective and had sprites on a rectangular grid.
- The game was a turn-based strategy game, focusing on vehicles, with a sci-fi setting. I think the planet it was set on was reddish-brown.
- The game was probably shareware, and I would have gotten the demo from a cover disc from a PC magazine published in the UK or Australia some time after 1994ish (possibly PC Pro, possibly PC Gamer?).
- This would likely have been in the mid to late 90s.
- The game was principally controlled with the mouse.
- The vehicles were uniformly one "tile" in size.

Other details:

- I don't recall resource gathering.
- I don't recall any specific science-fictional elements other than it being set on another planet and possibly some of the vehicles hovering and having some kind of laser or blaster weapon.
- Definitely not *M.A.X*., *Alpha Centauri*, or *Deadlock: Planetary Conquest*.
- The game had a strictly top-down view, not isometric, and I don't recall buildings being a significant element.

At about the same time, I would have been playing some other demos off of cover discs from the same magazine; games I remember playing this way include *Castle of the Winds*, *Mechwarrior 2*, *Jazz Jackrabbit*, *Duke Nukem 2*, and *Tyrian*.

I've gone through some abandonware websites and haven't found anything that resembles what I remember.

Comment: *Dune II* comes to mind, but it was a realtime RTS, and had its own interface as per https://youtu.be/tppjzT-su0Q?si=_fFANqUzNUel3RIP&t=181

Comment: I was more thinking of M.A.X., but it had its own interface as well.

Comment: First thought was Sid Meier's Alpha Centauri, or Deadlock: Planetary Conquest

Comment: The game was turn-based. I don't recall resource gathering. I didn't really understand the game when I played it - too young - but I don't recall any specific science-fictional elements other than it being set on another planet and possibly some of the vehicles hovering and having some kind of laser or blaster weapon.

Definitely not M.A.X, Alpha Centauri, or Deadlock: Planetary Conquest; the game had a strictly top-down view, not isometric, and I don't recall buildings being a significant element. The vehicles were uniformly one "tile" in size, I believe.

Comment: Maybe one of the games in the list at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_turn-based_strategy_video_games

Comment: Apart from the isometrics, "Fallen Haven" looks like a possible match: https://web.archive.org/web/20030704212023/http://www.cdmag.com/articles/001/104/fallen_haven_review.html

Comment: Like this one [Angels](https://nintendoeverything.com/turn-based-strategy-game-angels-on-tanks-coming-to-switch/) ?

Answer (score 1):

Probably not an exact match (it was not shareware and it didn't use the "standard" Windows buttons), but you could see if any of the games in the series of [Battle Isle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_Isle) could be a match.

- Visual from the top (even if I think they used a hexagonal grid)
- Turn based
- Set on a different planet
- Focus on vehicles, with little emphasis on buildings and no resource gathering
- The first games of the series were published in the 90s